# syntax error: invalid syntax -Django View

Tags: django-views

Below is my hello apps view.py

```
***def hello(request):
    num_visits = request.session.get('num_visits',0)+1
    request.session['num_visits'] = num_visits
    if num_visits > 4 : del(request.session['num_visits']
    return HttpResponse(';view count ='+str(num_visits))***
```

after compile, check below error appear on shell:
[Syntax Error - Invalid Syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ7VZ.png)

Can any expert provide some guidance ?

Answer (score 0):

`del` doesn't take arguments in parenthesis, it's an operator.

Change this line:

`del(request.session['num_visits']`

to:

`del request.session['num_visits']`

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the respond, i managed to address the problem, there was a missing ")" at the del line.